# How to modify a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to modify this link to go to

```
channels/params[:channel_id]/messages
```

here is the current link

```
<%= link_to pluralize(@channel.messages.size, 'message') %>
```

result of rake routes

```
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages"}  POST   /channels/:channel_id/messages(.:format)         
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}new_channel_message GET    /channels/:channel_id/messages/new(.:format)      
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"} edit_channel_message GET    /channels/:channel_id/messages/:id/edit(.:format) 
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"messages"}channel_message GET    /channels/:channel_id/messages/:id(.:format)      
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"} PUT    /channels/:channel_id/messages/:id(.:format)      
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"messages"} DELETE /channels/:channel_id/messages/:id(.:format)     
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"messages"} channels GET    /channels(.:format)                              
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"channels"} POST   /channels(.:format)                              
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"channels"}  new_channel GET    /channels/new(.:format)                          
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"channels"} edit_channel GET    /channels/:id/edit(.:format)                      
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"channels"}channel GET    /channels/:id(.:format)                           
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"channels"}PUT    /channels/:id(.:format)                           
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"channels"} DELETE /channels/:id(.:format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have used nested routes and if you redirect that link to index action in messages controller, then you can define your link like this:

`<%= link_to pluralize(@channel.messages.size, 'message'), channel_messages_path(@channel) %>`

Comment: That is how my link defined and I have nested messages inside of channels

Comment: I believe the error is in the code I added below, is this proper for when there is more than one messages? Because the link works when there are now messages but when there are messages I get this error "undefined method `edit_message_path' "

Comment: <div class="comment">
      <strong><%= link_to h(message.moderator), h(message) %></strong>
      <em>on <%= message.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y at %H:%M') %></em>
      <%=simple_format h(message.content) %>
      <p>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_message_path(message) %> |
        <%= link_to "Destroy", message, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
      </p>
    </div>

Comment: @Antarr- see you haven't defined regular route for **messages** controller. It is nested from **channels** routes. And obviously in rake routes list, also it's not visible. So better is to pass channel id also. Thus your code should be like this: `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_channel_message_path(channel, message) %>`

Comment: Thank you, I will reply once I get a change to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to "modify" it, since it most likely never worked anyway :)

Search for the path macro for your route, using:

```
rake routes
```

Then you can use the correct macro, which most likely is something like `channel_message`. You'll reach something like this:

```
<%= link_to pluralize(@channel.messages.size, 'message'), channel_message_path(@channel) %>
```

Comment: I posted the results above but im not sure how to use it, thanx for your time